# Прослушивание музыки на angular2 + web audio api

Tags: angular2, web-audio

Ребята. помогите, уже отчаялся Т_Т. Приведу сразу код:

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var context = new AudioContext();

function loadSound() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "http://localhost:3000/", true);
    request.responseType = "arraybuffer";

    request.onload = function() {
        var Data = request.response;
        console.log(Data);
        process(Data);
    };

    request.send();
}

function process(Data) {
    var source = context.createBufferSource(); // Create Sound Source
    context.decodeAudioData(Data, function(buffer) {
        console.log(buffer);
        source.buffer = buffer;
        source.connect(context.destination);
        source.start(context.currentTime);
    })
}
loadSound();
```

Это работает,  сервак отдает и музычка играет, вот собственно код сервера:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var file = __dirname + '/upload/star.mp3';
    res.set({ 'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg' });
    var readStream = fs.createReadStream(file);
    readStream.pipe(res);
});
```

А вот этому парню все по-барабану, вроде трэк приходит, но не играет:

```
  export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app works!';

  constructor(public http: Http) {}

  process(data) {
    let context = new AudioContext();
    let source = context.createBufferSource(); // Create Sound Source
    context.decodeAudioData(data).then(buffer => {
      console.log(buffer);
      source.buffer = buffer;
      source.connect(context.destination);
      source.start(context.currentTime);
    })
  }

  play() {
    this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/")
      .map((res: Response) => res.arrayBuffer())
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.process(res);
      },
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log('done')
      )
  }

}
```

Собственно может кто уже сталкивался, что делали в этом случае?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кому будет полезно, пропустил заголовки в запросе

```
play() {
let options = new RequestOptions({ responseType: ResponseContentType.ArrayBuffer}); // вот то, чего не хватало
this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/", options)
  .map((res: Response) => res.arrayBuffer())
  .subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
    this.process(res);
  },
    err => console.error(err),
    () => console.log('done')
  )
```

}